# How do I view PFX file information in a visual manner?

Tags: encryption, certificate, pfx

I have a PFX file on my drive. I want to see the certificate chain for it. How do I see this? I am asking for a visual tool since I'm sure this won't be the last time I need to view certificate information, and I know of no tool that does this...

Answer (score 33):

```
certutil -dump filename.pfx
```

MS doc: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx

Although that is for Win 8 or Server 2012.  I have Win 7 on my development machine - not sure if this program is present by default or came with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 10):

Below also works fine in cmd:

> openssl pkcs12 -info -in **path to cert**

for more info check these links :

https://superuser.com/questions/580697/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-pfx-file-on-windows/1212800

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

In case if you run into openssl issue, means if it's not installed, download openssl and refer path to openssl.exe in bin instead of openssl.

Comment: Note that newer versions of openssl may not support older algorithms, such as (oddly in 2022) the version required to convert GoDaddy certs to the pfx file type required by Azure Web Apps. If you get an error with the term "unsupported" you may find luck by using an older release of your linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

This question is, I think, better suited to [superuser](https://superuser.com/). A PFX file is just a pkcs12 file, and the [openssl pkcs12](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html) utility can be used to parse it. Experiment with the options to get the output you're looking for.